# Issue with UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, whatsapp, uiactivityviewcontroller, ios11.3

I am using UIActivityViewController for image sharing,

In this, I am getting an error,

```
SLRemoteComposeViewController: (this may be harmless) viewServiceDidTerminateWithError: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}
```

In WhatsApp sharing.

My code is as below,

```
 NSArray *excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeMessage];

    UIActivityViewController *activityView = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[_originalImage] applicationActivities:nil];

    [[activityView popoverPresentationController] setBarButtonItem:btn];

    activityView.excludedActivityTypes = excludedActivityTypes;

    activityView.completionWithItemsHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *activityError) {

        if(completed && [activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll]){

            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

        }
    };

    [self presentViewController:activityView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Does anyone having any idea about this?

Comment: hey UIActivityViewController open or not?

Comment: yes open working with everyone accept WhatsApp

Comment: can you set LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in .plist ?

Comment: added below, <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
 <array>
  <string>whatsapp</string>
 </array>

Comment: I am facing this same issue. Can u guide me how to solve this ???

Comment: @McDonal_11, use compressed image